# JFace and FieldEditor

Tags: java, jface

From Eclipse RCP, I'm building a preference page using Field Editors (http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Field-Editors/field_editors.html)

I'm trying to use the field editor BooleanFieldEditor, subclass of FieldEditor.

My issue is that in the javadoc, I don't find the function to change the state (checked/unchecked) of this field editor.

Where is the setChecked(boolean) function? :-)
I missed something?

Comment: Looking at the Javadoc for BooleanFieldEditor, it appears that you have to use the doLoad or doLoadDefault method to set the boolean field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it by accessing the preference store's APIs.

```
getPreferenceStore().setValue(preferenceID, value);
```

where **preferenceID** is the name of the boolean preference 
(i.e. `new BooleanFieldEditor(preferenceID, label, parent);`), 
and the **value** is *true/false*.

You get the current value for the ID with

```
getPreferenceStore().getBoolean(preferenceID);
```

Comment: In the Preferences window of the application, I use a PreferenceStore. But for this case, I don't use it. I tried this without conviction but it does not work: `IPreferenceStore ps = new PreferenceStore(); expandedEditor.setPreferenceStore(ps); ps.setValue("expandedEditor", true);` `expandedEditor` is the BooleanFieldEditor.

Answer (score -1):

Since this control is managing preferences, I would suggest using a [preference initializer](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_runtime_preferences.html?cp=2_1_1_30).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Could you explain your answer?